# Get other values in datasource of a dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, dataset, datasource

I have connected a Stored Procedure to a DropDownList

The Stored Procedure has 3 values RepID, RepName, and RepRef

The DropDownList has 2 values which are DataTextField and DataValueField

I connected DataTextField to RepName and DataValueField to RepID

I want to get the RepRef too

how can I do that

Here is my code

```
                conn.Open(); 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mySP", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddlReps.DataSource = dt;
                    ddlReps.DataTextField = "RepName";
                    ddlReps.DataValueField = "RepID";
                    ddlReps.DataBind();
                }
```

If User selected Report called "Cities" which has ID = 16

How Can I get the RepRef from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ and add add a new property on your anonymous type the way you want to format it:

```
var datasource = dt.Select(x=> new {
                 x.RepID,
                 x.RepName,
                 x.RepRef,
                 DisplayField = String.Format("{0} {1}", x.RepName, x.RepRef)
             }).ToList();

ddlReps.DataSource = datasource;
ddlReps.DataValueField = "RepID";
ddlReps.DataTextField = "DisplayField";
ddlReps.DataBind();
```